# How can I make myself invisible in Skype for Windows 8 without becoming invisible in Messenger?

Tags: windows-8, skype, windows-8-people-app, windows-8-messaging-app

I'd prefer for my Skype contacts not to know when I am online. But if I mark myself as "invisible" in skype, it also marks as "invisible" accross the entire OS. Among other things, this signs me out of facebook chat.

Is there any way (without uninstalling the Skype app) to go invisible in Skype only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible if you have merged your Skype and microsoft account.

Answer (score 3):

If you have merged your Microsoft and Skype account then you can request for Skype to unmerge it by giving them a call.